# What if two blocks complete their POW at same time

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

Let's consider a scenario: suppose 2 miners pick up 2 different unconfirmed transactions and they complete the proof of work. If miner A adds the block first to blockChain then the block produced by miner B be will be wrong/useless because the last_Hash he used is now wrong and he has to use the last_hash of miner A that is added right a second before he was going to add his block.
e.g.

```html
 

 <b>current chian: block1--block2--block3</b>
    <table>
     <tr>
             <td>Miner A  </td>
            <td>Miner B</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>LastHast=block3-hash<br>    
      currentHast=SHA(block3's_hash,timestemp,data,nonce)  <br>
      proof of work  <br>    
      add---- Successfully add block4 <br>
      </td> 
       
      <td>LastHast=block3-hash<br>    
      currentHast=SHA(block3's_hash,timestemp,data,nonce) <br>
      proof of work  <br>    
      add---- Fail because the last hash is now block4's not block3's So currentHash is wrong so the proof of work<br>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

**
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Double spending is avoided by having other miners verify the proposed change on the ledger.
In your case two miners verified the transaction, published the result to the network and depending on your protocol this might be fine so the change on the ledger will take place.

Apart from that a timestamp server that ensures that you will always build on top of a unique chain of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The valid transactions are always on the longest chain, by longest, I mean the block number is bigger.

If **minerA** and **minerB** finished PoW at the same time,  a **fork** is made

At the current time, both **minerA** and **minerB** transaction is stored on the fullnode, and the fullnode is waiting for the next block to be produced.

During the next block time, **minerA** finished PoW first, then the fork (data chain) on **minerA** is considered longer, thus **minerA** become the longest chain and considered valid, block on **minerB** is considered non-valid, and discared.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is happening all the time, and the protocol is built to deal with it.

Let’s assume 2 miners, A and B, that find the PoW for a different set of transactions at the same time.

The next thing this miners will do is to broadcast their newly found blocks over the network.

This broadcast is not instantaneous (light speed is not instantaneous) and so miners near A will receive first the broadcast from A, and miners near B will receive first the broadcast from B.

At that instant, A neighbours will start working on a new block on top of the A block, while B neighbours will start working in a new block on top of the B block.

The networked has just forked, part of the network is working on a blockchain that ends on block A, other part is working on a blockchain that ends on block B.

Let’s assume now 2 new miners, C and D. C is a A neighbour and is working on a new block on top of the A block. D is a B neighbour and is working on a new block on top of the B block.

Imagine that C finds the PoW for a new block first than D. C will broadcast this block to the network. Eventually, D will receive this C block and will realize that the blockchain X -> A -> C has more PoW then the one its working on, X -> B.

By the protocol rules, D will discard immediately what it was working on, and will start to work on the PoW for a new block on top of X -> A -> C, thus resolving the network fork.